# How to unit test a function that reads from or writes to files?

Tags: javascript, file, unit-testing, jasmine, electron

My electron application is saving parameters in config files.

How can I unit test the `loadConfig()` and `saveConfig()` functions without modifying the real data once it goes to prod?

I'd gladly show you what I've already done, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Please, can you post a source code block that includes the function (or a sample function) and the import statements of the tools you use to manipulate files?

Comment: I'll do what I can. TDD implies that I don't have any code yet ;-)

Comment: Ok, then good luck

Comment: Thanks, I see your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your main motive is to test whether you are able to load and save the data or not. Considering if it is a blank file in the beginning of the test.

Step 1. Write some data to the file. 
 
Step 2. Read the same data. 
Step 3. Since you yourself write the data, in the beginning, therefore you should know in advance that what exactly that data was. 
Step 4. Assert the same data you already have with the data you got after performing read operation. 
Step 5. Clear out all the data in that file. 

This will assure you whether what you are writing and reading back is correct or not. 
You can perform this operation on some dummy file as well, as the main motive is to test read and write operation on the file.

Comment: OK, but what if the file has been changed by the user? The "clear out" step destroys their data. Testing a dummy file means changing the code of the function.

Comment: That's why I mentioned that you can also perform this algorithm on some dummy file, since, your main motive of testing the read and write operation will be completed.

Comment: No worries, keep coding ;)